# In python polars filter and aggregate dict of lists

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have got a dataframe with string representation of json:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({ 
        "json": [
            '{"x":[0,1,2,3], "y":[10,20,30,40]}',
            '{"x":[0,1,2,3], "y":[10,20,30,40]}',
            '{"x":[0,1,2,3], "y":[10,20,30,40]}'
        ] 
    })
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ json                              │
│ ---                               │
│ str                               │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ {"x":[0,1,2,3], "y":[10,20,30,40… │
│ {"x":[0,1,2,3], "y":[10,20,30,40… │
│ {"x":[0,1,2,3], "y":[10,20,30,40… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Now I would like to calculate the **average** for **y** where **x > 0** and **x < 3** for each row.

---

This is my current working solution:

First evaluate the string -> dict and then create a dataframe, which is filtered by x.

```
df = df.with_columns([
    pl.col('json').apply(lambda x: pl.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(x)).filter((pl.col('x') < 3) & (pl.col('x') > 0))['y'].mean())
])
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌──────┐
│ json │
│ ---  │
│ f64  │
╞══════╡
│ 25.0 │
│ 25.0 │
│ 25.0 │
└──────┘
```

---

This works fine, but for large datasets the apply functions is slowing down the process significantly.

Is there a more elegant and faster way of doing it?

Comment: If you actually have JSON data you can use [`.str.json_extract()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.json_extract.html#polars.Expr.str.json_extract) - or `pl.read_ndjson` / `pl.read_json` - the example you've shown is not valid JSON, it has single quotes - and judging by the use of `ast` - it's a "stringified" python dict?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It actually can be both (stringified python dict or JSON). Nevertheless it is still not clear to me how to avoid the apply. By using .str.json_extract you get a struct, but then I would have to explode it somehow in order to do the filtering and aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### json.loads()

To parse JSON strings in Polars you can use [`.str.json_decode()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.json_decode.html#polars.Expr.str.json_decode) (i.e. the equivalent of `json.loads`)

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col("json").str.json_decode())
```

```py
shape: (3, 1)
┌──────────────────────────────┐
│ json                         │
│ ---                          │
│ struct[2]                    │
╞══════════════════════════════╡
│ {[0, 1, … 3],[10, 20, … 40]} │
│ {[0, 1, … 3],[10, 20, … 40]} │
│ {[0, 1, … 3],[10, 20, … 40]} │
└──────────────────────────────┘
```

#### unnest()

The "JSON object" becomes a Polars struct which you can [`.unnest`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) into separate columns.

As the lists are of the same length, you can `.explode()` them both at the same time.

```py
(df.with_columns(pl.col("json").str.json_decode())
   .unnest("json")
   .explode("x", "y")
)
```

```py
shape: (12, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 10  │
│ 1   ┆ 20  │
│ 2   ┆ 30  │
│ 3   ┆ 40  │
│ …   ┆ …   │
│ 0   ┆ 10  │
│ 1   ┆ 20  │
│ 2   ┆ 30  │
│ 3   ┆ 40  │
└─────┴─────┘
```

If we add a row count before exploding, we can use it in a `.group_by` to rebuild each "row" after filtering.

```py
(df.with_row_count()
   .with_columns(pl.col("json").str.json_decode())
   .unnest("json")
   .explode("x", "y")
   .filter(pl.col("x").is_between(1, 2))
   .group_by("row_nr")
   .agg(pl.col("y").mean())
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────┬──────┐
│ row_nr ┆ y    │
│ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ u32    ┆ f64  │
╞════════╪══════╡
│ 0      ┆ 25.0 │
│ 1      ┆ 25.0 │
│ 2      ┆ 25.0 │
└────────┴──────┘
```

#### List/Struct Namespaces

As well as unnesting/exploding into columns/rows, Polars also has the [`.list`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/lists/) and [`.struct`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/structs/) namespaces.

```py
(df.with_columns(parsed = pl.col("json").str.json_decode())
   .with_columns(mean = 
      pl.col("parsed").struct["y"].list.gather(
         pl.col("parsed").struct["x"].list.eval(
            pl.element().is_between(1, 2).arg_true()
         )
      )
      .list.mean()
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────┬──────┐
│ json                              ┆ parsed                       ┆ mean │
│ ---                               ┆ ---                          ┆ ---  │
│ str                               ┆ struct[2]                    ┆ f64  │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════╪══════╡
│ {"x":[0,1,2,3], "y":[10,20,30,40… ┆ {[0, 1, … 3],[10, 20, … 40]} ┆ 25.0 │
│ {"x":[0,1,2,3], "y":[10,20,30,40… ┆ {[0, 1, … 3],[10, 20, … 40]} ┆ 25.0 │
│ {"x":[0,1,2,3], "y":[10,20,30,40… ┆ {[0, 1, … 3],[10, 20, … 40]} ┆ 25.0 │
└───────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution! Sometimes you do not to see the wood for the trees.

Comment: Note that as of [polars 0.19.15](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.19.15) `str.json_extract` is deprecated in favour of `str.json_decode`.

Comment: @Hericks Thanks. I think `.arr` needs to be updated also. Feel free to edit the answer. (I can do it later if needed.)